# jQuery - get the first class only from a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

The element looks like this:

```
<li class="blah active"> ... </li>
```

`jQuery.attr('class')` will return both classes.
How can I get only the 1st class ('blah' in this case) with jQuery?

Comment: the problem is, that if you add/remove classes via jquery, it will not save the correct order of the items. so maybe you want to check, if that class is in the list, instead of getting the first one.

Comment: In general I would not trust all browsers to give them back to you in the same order.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You need to [`split`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) that into an array:

```
console.log(jQuery('selector').attr('class').split(' ')[0]);
```

Comment: Or use a regex: `var first = $('#foo').attr('class').replace(/^(\S*).*/, '$1');`

Comment: In this case, you should use `prop` instead of `attr`.

Answer (score 9):

```
var first = jQuery.attr('class').split(" ")[0];
```

Comment: and he said "`jQuery.attr('class')` will return both classes", which indicates that by `jQuery` he meant an instance of the jQuery object, not the contructor function which invokes `jQuery.fn.init`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following to get the first class only from an element:

```
var firstClass = jQuery('selector')[0].classList[0]
```