# Jquery: how to get one class without .split()

Tags: jquery

I have a div with two class.

```
<div class="one two"></div>
```

I need to get first of them without **.split()** callback.

```
$(this).parent('div[class]').attr('class').split(' ')[0]
```

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

**UPD**: Why I need this? ) 
Because then I use **split()**, code inspector in Chrome said **exactly** :

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined

аnd some function not work properly.

Comment: What wrong with `split()`? What don't you want to use it?

Comment: What's wrong with using .split() ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203966/jquery-get-the-first-class-only-from-a-element The value of class is a single string regardless of how many individual class names make up the string. I can't think of a way to do it *without* split()! But yeah, what is the problem with split()..?

Comment: **Frederic, Didier** - when I use `split()` with my js, some functions are not work properly, and code inspector sad that `Cannot call method 'Split' of undefined `

Comment: @Nixon that is a different problem entirely

Comment: @Nixon - If you've copied that error message exactly your problem was that you were trying to call `Split` rather than `split`. Note the lower-case `s`.

Comment: @Nixon. the proper method is called `split` (in lowercase). More generally, javascript function names are camelCase.

Comment: Is that error saying split is undefined or can't call split *on* undefined?

Comment: **32bitkid, James Allardice** i've updated post and write what said exactly code inspector.

And **split** write with lower-case **s**

Answer (score 1):

`/\S*/.exec(this.parentNode.className)[0];` will give the first class of the parent class, if any.

This method is more efficient than your current method: **Your method returns an empty string when the `class` attribute starts with a space.**

Comment: As a response to the updated question, ensure that `this` points to a child of your `<div>`. *If `this` is not a direct child, you might want to use [`.closest('div[class]')`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/).

Answer (score 1):

If you're really adverse to using `split()`, you can combine [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) and [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr):

```
var classes = $(this).parent("div[class]").attr("class");
var firstClass = classes.substr(0, classes.indexOf(" "));
```

However, the code above will only work if there are more than one class name in `classes`.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what you are trying to do with the info but if you are checking if he has `one` as class just try it like this.
I used a button since I needed a child to trigger the event ;)
http://jsfiddle.net/c3VdH/