# How can I get the first word only out of a string with javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following:

```
var html = document.documentElement;
var class = html.className;
```

This returns "black ng-scope";

How can I make it so that class just returns the first word?

Comment: Already asked : http://stackoverflow.com/q/3203966/1636522

Answer (score 9):

You can use

```
var firstClass = html.className.split(' ')[0]
```

Answer (score 3):

An alternative way of getting the separated class names is by using `classList`. see [browser support](http://caniuse.com/classlist) and [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList)

Comment: Great answer did not know about `classList` thank you. I will add this to my answer as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
> "hey there".split(" ")[0]
"hey"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var classes = class.split(" "); // Returns an array
var firstclass = classes[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Another idea is using regular expressions if you could have other word boundaries than space.

```
var reg = /(.+?)(?:\s|$)/,
    match = html.className.match(reg);

if (match) {
    match[1]; // Your match
}
```

This has the added benefit of matching more than a single space.

**EDIT:** If you are using this to strictly get all classes of an HTML element and you are targeting sufficiently new browsers use `classList` like *Jakob W* suggested.