# Keep the name of class until the first space

Tags: jquery

I use this to take the name of the body class:

```
$("body").attr("class")
```

In source code I can see this:

```
<body class="mybodyclass">
```

but when I use the first command in console I take this:

```
"mybodyclass wrap-in wrap-out"
```

From the result how it could be possible to take the first word only?

Comment: You could split by spaces class attribute and shift it but **why** would you need that???  `var firstClass= $("body").attr("class").split(' ').shift();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3203966/jquery-get-the-first-class-only-from-a-element), the quickest solution is to split the result, like this:

```
$("body").attr("class").split(' ')[0];
```

Answer (score -1):

Look at [.removeClass()](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) And [.addClass()](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/)

You can use

```
var class = $("body").attr("class").split(' ')[0];
$("body).removeClass().addClass(class)';`
```